# Seeking a place to stay in Miami Beach, Florida near or with a heated, outside pool

Tags: accommodation, florida, miami

Are there any outdoor, heated public pools in or near Miami Beach, Florida, either open to the public or at a hotel or private rental?  (I think I found one such rental but it was many hundreds of dollars a night, out of my price range.)

Comment: With highs in the 80s and lows in the 70s?!

Comment: @MichaelHampton Average high of 74 and low of 61 in January, from 1981-2010, per https://www.currentresults.com/Weather/Florida/Places/miami-beach-temperatures-by-month-average.php